# if $A^2 \in M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ is diagonalizable then so is $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove:

> if $A^2 \in M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ is diagonalizable then so is $A$.

I'm pretty confident this is not true, but I've tried and tried to find a counter example without success. If someone contradicts this, I'd appreciate if you can outline your thought process when constructing the matrix $A$.

Also, another question in the same batch, asks:

> Let $p(t)=t(t-0.25)(t-1)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A^2$, is $A$ diagonalizable?

I'm thinking this is suppose to answer the previous question, assuming the answer here is false.

Here I know $A^2$ is diagonalizable, but I haven't made any substantial progress other than that.
I know I can go from the eigenvalues of $A$ to the eigenvalues of $A^k$, but not the other way around.

Comment: Daniel, I have changed the notation to $M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ which is the standard notation for set of all  $3 \times 3$ real matrices. I hope that isn't a problem. If it is, then please rollback.

Comment: @Chandru, not at all, thank you.

Comment: This is not true for matrices with a nilpotent Jordan component. However, if $A$ is non-singular, and we switch the field to complex numbers, then it is true. A slightly more general case (some power known to be diagonalizable) of this was recently discussed in http://fora.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=71107

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. The idea is that the null matrix is diagonalizable, but there exist matrices which satisfy $A^2=0$ and $A$ is not diagonalizable.

For the second question, note that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are distinct, and therefore the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, which implies that $A$ is diagonalizable.

If $P_A$ denotes the minimal polynomial of $A$ then $P_{A^2}(X^2)$ is an annulating polynomial for $A$. This means that $P_A|P_{A^2}(X^2)$. If $A^2$ is diagonalizable then $P_{A^2}$ has simple roots. If zero is not  root of $P_{A^2}$ then all roots of $P_{A^2}(X^2)$ are simple so all roots of $P_A$ are simple and $A$ is diagonizable. (here we need to be sure that the roots of $P_A$ are all in the field of elements of $A$; if we work on $\Bbb{C}$ then we are fine)

So if zero is not an eigenvalue of $A$ then $A^2$ diagonizable implies $A$ diagonizable.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the second problem is yes.  In general, the (in general complex) eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$.  In this case $A^2$ has the eigenvalues $0$, $\frac{1}{4}$, and $1$.  Therefore $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, either $\frac{1}{2}$ or $-\frac{1}{2}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and either $1$ or $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.  This means that $A$ has $3$ distinct real eigenvalues, which implies it is diagonalizable.  The key is that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are distinct and nonnegative, which implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct and real.

Edit: I accidentally overlapped somewhat with Beni Bogosel's earlier answer.  (More was added after I started writing.)

Comment: So if $A^2$ had a negative eigenvalue, say $-1$, the same argument would not work? Because then it's possible that $A$ characteristic polynomial has $i$ as one of its roots, which is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: @daniel.jackson: Yes, except you can strengthen your statements.  If $A^2$ has a negative eigenvalue, then $A$ necessarily has a nonreal eigenvalue, which implies it is not diagonalizable in $M_n(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Why must it have a nonreal eigenvalue?

Comment: It follows from the fact mentioned above (of which I have not provided a proof) that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are precisely the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$, while squares of real numbers are nonnegative real numbers.

Comment: I see. Could you be so kind to provide a proof (a general idea will be fine too)?

Comment: Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$.  Then $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible, which implies $(A-\lambda I)(A+\lambda I)=A^2-\lambda^2 I$ is not invertible.  Therefore $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$.  Next suppose that neither of the square roots of a complex number $\lambda$, say $\pm w$, is an eigenvalue of $A$.  Then $A-w I$ and $A+wI$ are invertible, so $(A-wI)(A+wI)=A^2-\lambda I$ is invertible.  This implies that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $A^2$.

Comment: See also the related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28654/spectrum-of-the-operator

Answer (score 1):

Try $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1&0 \\ 1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.
I found it by considering the complex matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&i&0 \\ 0&0&-i\end{pmatrix}$ and finding its characteristic polynomial, then using rational canonical form over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The idea here is that over $\mathbb{C}$, being diagonalizable is equivalent to having distinct eigenvalues.  So, over $\mathbb{C}$, your question is true: $A^2$ diagonalizable implies $A$ diagonalizable.  So to find a counterexample, you need a diagonal matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ whose eigenvalues are not all real, but whose squares are all real.

Comment: uh? having distinct eigenvalues is sufficient but not necessary for being diagonalizable

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I meant distinct roots in its minimal polynomial.

Comment: No, $A^2$ diagonalizable does not imply $A$ diagonalizable. It doesn't matter what field this is over. See Beni Bogosel's answer.

Comment: I have been working with invertible matrices the whole time!!

Answer (score 0):

To the second question: yes. If all eigenvalues of $A^2$ are pairwise distinct, then so are the eigenvalues of $A$, because if $Av=\lambda v$ then $A^2 v = \lambda ^2 v$, so $\ker(A-\lambda I) \subset \ker(A^2 - \lambda^2 I)$.

A matrix with pairwise distinct eigenvalues is  diagonalizable. That's a simple and well known theorem.