# $A^2$ is diagonalizable leads to $A$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

If $A^2$ is diagonalizable, is it necessary true that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Also, the opposite:
If $A$ is diagonalizable, is it necessary true that $A^2$ is diagonalizable?

I'm not sure yet, tried to prove with $A^2 = P^{-1}DP$ , but no success.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49864/if-a2-in-m-3-mathbbr-is-diagonalizable-then-so-is-a) for  the first question. For the second, if $A=P^{-1}DP$, what is $(P^{-1}DP)(P^{-1}DP)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first proposition is false, as for example $A^2 = 0$ for nonzero (nilpotent) $A$.

For example: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Of course if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A^2$ (and indeed any polynomial in $A$) is also diagonalizable:  $D = P^{-1} A P$ diagonal implies $D^2 = P^{-1} A^2 P$.

Comment: Why? I thought about saying: if $A^2$ is diagonalizable, that it might has a characteristic polynomial which won't be the same characteristic polynomial for $A$.

Comment: Still didn't get the answer, feeling stupid. if $A^2$ is diagonalizable and it equals to zero, how can $A$ be the matrix u just posted?

Comment: ^More to the point, the ring of matrices is not a domain.

Comment: @hardmath Brilliant! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

It is actually true iif $A^2$ has only positive eigenvalues.

If $\pi$ is a polynomial that factors completely into distinct factors (hope I'm getting this right in english, please correct otherwise) and for which $\pi(A^2)=0$ (such a polynomial exists because $A^2$ is diagonalizable), ie :
$$\pi(X)=\prod_i (X-\lambda_i)$$
with distincts $\lambda_i>0$, and $\pi(A^2)=\prod_i (A^2-\lambda_i I)=0$

Then $P(X)=\pi(X^2)=\prod_i (X^2-\lambda_i)=\prod_i (X-\sqrt{\lambda_i})(X+\sqrt{\lambda_i})$ is also completely factored into distinct factors and verify $P(A)=0$ which imply with kernel lemma that $A$ is also diagonalizable.

The other side is trivial as mentionned by hardmath

Comment: Well, $A^2-\lambda_i$ should be $A^2-\lambda_i I$.

Comment: @enzotib Yes, that's a bad habit I have. I'll correct it for the sake of compleness). Anyway, the other answer was accepted

Comment: I upvoted this, not only because the circumstances in which the proposition holds are worth articulating, but because the method of proof points to another class of "counterexamples" than the one I gave. The trick here is that the real numbers give square roots of all the positive eigenvalues. If the field we work over lacks square roots for an eigenvalue, say $\mathbb{Q}$ lacking $\sqrt{2}$, we can construct say $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, which cannot be diagonalized simply because the diagonal entries don't exist in the field.

Comment: Why positive? It seems that as long as there is no zero, we are good.

Comment: @athanoslee:  You are right over the reals, see [this related Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4030914/a-in-m-n-mathbbc-invertible-and-a2-is-diagonalizable-prove-a-is-dia).  The typo "iif" makes it look like an "iff" was intended, but I don't think that's what Bertrand R meant.